# Trouble installing pytorch with conda

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install pytorch using conda.

I believe there are known problems with pytorch and python 3.9, so I set up a virtual environment with python 3.8.11

I then activate this virtual environment and try to install pytorch using conda with

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

Everything seems to be going fine until the end. Here is the full stack trace:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::cudatoolkit-11.1.1-heb2d755_7'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::cudatoolkit-11.1.1-heb2d755_7
location of failed script: C:\Users\Xavier Gonzalez\anaconda3\envs\venv\Scripts\.cudatoolkit-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr: Access is denied.

return code: 1

()
```

I have looked over the web but have not found anything I could use. Does anyone have an idea of the right direction, or a conceptual understanding of what is going wrong?

Comment: "Access is denied" -- you don't have write permissions. Run the conda install command as root instead of a normal user

Answer (score 0):

Good news! There is an extremely simple fix

The official pytorch website (https://pytorch.org/) indicates that the correct command is

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```